# How to compile linux bridge?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming

I am working on a networking project and for some reason I need to modify the source code of the bridge that is used in Linux. I was wondering how to add http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bridge/ source codes into my Ubuntu distribution.

I am having Ubuntu 16.04 with a 4.4.0-64-generic kernel version. In my : `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-66/net/bridge` there is just : `Kconfig` and `Makefile` files with `netfilter` folder.

Could you please point me out to some solutions ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Everything is already there. I am wondering what help you need? You just need to enable the `CONFIG_BRIDGE` ***(including most of files)*** and other config option of  `Makefile`  from the kernel config  ***(Which I am assuming already enabled)*** to compile the entire source code.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I want to have the source code of the bridge to modify it in my Ubuntu distribution. However, the source code of the bridge is not present in my /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0.66/net/bridge. Did you get my point @vinod maverick ? thank you

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode  and 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
These two links will help you to build your own kernel in existing ubuntu distributions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the sources code of the kernel that you are currently running you can:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Modify the driver code and then compile.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try it and let you know if it worked. regards